# nodejs arrow function with expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you can return an expression from an arrow function:

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
     // equivalent to:  => { return expression; }
```

but this doesn't seem to work as I would expect (nodejs 4.2.3)

```
> [1,2,3].map(i => i);
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> [1,2,3].map(i => {});
[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Shouldn't the 2nd example return 3 empty objects? Or am I missing something?

Comment: When in doubt, you could always feed this to babel and see what it transpiles it into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), the body of fat arrow function can be written as either a single expression or a series of statements wrapped into `{}` (just as you write bodies of plain old functions).

The point is, if parser encounters `{` after the `=>`, it goes with the second option. Now, it doesn't matter whether or not you use empty object literal or full object literal (like `{ a: 2 }` in the first edit of this answer) - it's never treated as object literal, only as a function's body.

And what happens if function doesn't have a `return` statement? Right - this function returns `undefined`. That's why you get three of those as result of `map` (both for `=> {}` and for `=> { a: 2 }`).

To get three empty objects instead, just wrap `{}` into `()`, like this:

```
[1,2,3].map(i => ({}));
```

... as it forces the parser to go with `expression` path.

Comment: In fact, `{ a: 2 }` is a block as well

Comment: @vkurchatkin In fact, it's not treated as a code block (otherwise it'd have been evaluated to `2`, `a:` considered as a label), but as a function's body. That's important distinction - and I admit I didn't know about it. Live and learn. )